# How would I represent the following menu structure in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
Soccer
  Australia
    Melbourne
    Sydney
  New Zealand
    Christchurch
Tennis
  United Kingdom
    Kensington
    London
    Manchester
```

I have tried multidimensional arrays however it becomes awkward because of the different lengths. I have also experimented with key/value pairs however again I encountered difficulty because in a way there are only values and no keys. I have tried to represent the hierarchy visually.  To clarify Sydney is a child of Australia. Australia is a child of Soccer. Soccer is a sibling of Tennis and so on.

Edit: I'm looking for a solution that does not require any knowledge of the actual data.  In other words I could swap out "Soccer" with "Baseball" and a simple algorithm which just prints out the data structure should not break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JSON:

```
{
    "Soccer": {
        "Australia": [
            "Melbourne",
            "Sydney"
        ],
        "NewZealand": [
            "Christchurch"
        ]
    },
    "Tennis": {
        "UnitedKingdom": [
            "Kensington",
            "London",
            "Manchester"
        ]
    }
}
```

Here's a loop through the data:

```
for ( sport in data ) {
    // print sport here
    countries =  data[sport];    
    for ( country in countries ) {
        // print country here
        cities = countries[country];
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            // print city here
        };
    };
};​
```

Can be seen on jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2p6g3/18/

Comment: I added a small amendment to the original question. Does JSON still work with the additional requirement? Thanks

Comment: Should be fine. Would you like me to add some simple code that loops through and prints the data?

Comment: If you could that would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"sport": [
    {
        "name": "Soccer",
        "place": [
            {
                "country": "Australia",
                "city": [
                    {
                        "name": "Melbourne"
                    },
                    {
                        "nam": "Sdney"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "country": "NewZealand",
                "city": [
                    {
                        "name": "Christchurch"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Tennis",
        "place": [
            {
                "country": "UnitedKingdom",
                "city": [
                    {
                        "name": "Manchester"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

loop through the array of object to get required fields:

```
sport[].name // name of the sports
sport[].place[].country // country name
sport[].place[].city[].name // city name
```

Comment: This isn't a very accurate representation of the data.